# Shift array values down the the array to make room for new value in 1st position of the array in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a pseudo-sorter to sort values from 1 array and paste the results to a second array smaller by shifting values down the second array

since the position of the original array list is important, I can't just sort the original list and paste the top 3 smallest values to the new array. This method is only permissible.

So lets say for the size of array2 = 3

```
array2 (1,1) = 2
array2 (2,1) = 4
array2 (3,1) = 5
```

NEW SMALLER VALUE FOUND in array1 = 1

```
array2 (1,1) = 1
array2 (2,1) = 2
array2 (3,1) = 4
```

as it iterates thru the 1st array, it checks if its smaller than the value of the 1st value of the second array, then it shifts all the value within second array by 1 (the last number of 2nd array remove out of the array) to make room in the first position of array2 for that smaller value.

This only goes thru the array1 once (does not loop to find the "true" smallest)

It skips every "nthsteps" when iterating thru array1 for the sake of efficiency.

This is the code I got so far, yet it doesn't really work:

```
Function pseudo_sorter_smallest(range1 As Range, size As Integer, nthsteps As Integer)
    Dim array1() As Double
    Dim array2() As Double
    
    ncount = range1.Cells.Count
    
    ReDim array1(1 To ncount, 1 To 1) As Double
    ReDim array2(1 To size, 1 To 2) As Double
    
    For i = 1 To ncount
        array1(i, 1) = range1(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    array2(1, 1) = array1(1, 1)
    array2(1, 2) = i
    
    For i = 1 To ncount Step nthsteps
            If array1(i, 1) < array2(1, 1) Then
                For j = 1 To size - 1
                    array2(j + 1, 1) = array2(j, 1)
                    array2(j + 1, 2) = array2(j, 2)
                Next j
            array2(1, 1) = array1(i, 1)
            array2(1, 2) = i
            End If
    Next i
    pseudo_sorter_smallest = array2()
```

End Function

The thing is im trying to make the second array size dynamic and able to to change based on number of values 2nd array requires.

I am no expert in VBA or coding in general, so I'd appreciate if the solution is similar to how I write my code.

the desired output is like this in excel for Pseudo__sorter_smallest(data, 3, 5) with range "data" with 100 entries of random values:

```
values | position of values in data     
-----------------------------------
  1    |           24
  2    |           20
  4    |            3
```

*position in of values in data means that e.g. value 1 can located in the 24th row of the data range.

any inputs will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, forget (for now) about that pseudo sorting/shifting and try focusing on **what you really try accomplishing**. If I would say that you need to add an element (minimum, maximum from another one, it doesn't matter) to an existing array and after that you want sorting `Ascending` the updated array, will it be a correct understanding?

Comment: Or you want placing the new added element in front of all existing?

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes the latter is i what I'm trying to accomplish. The numbers will be used to get the row positions of the values in array1, which will be then used to extract the dates corresponding to those values in another column (hence the reason the array1 cannot be sorted)

Comment: Read up on the ArrayList object.  You can insert your values at the location of your choice.  When you have finished, you can get back to an Array using the .ToArray method.

Comment: I cannot understand too much from your clarification answer... So, do you want adding a new element to an existing array and want it to be the first? If  not, **what do you want**? VBA does not care where from this value/element comes... I do not care about "The numbers will be used to get the row positions etc.", only if you want confusing us... Please, try focusing on what you try accomplishing, not on **how you do/try**. Your code is strange, no offence...

Comment: Is this a VBA question or a VB.NET question? They are different languages so it's not both. Please remove the irrelevant tag. People watch tags for a reason and don't want to be lured into irrelevant questions.

Comment: none taken, my bad. I will update the code and put an output to better explain.

Comment: The edit confuses me more, I'm afraid... What is the meaning of "position of values in data"? Which "positions" so big if you look to talk about an array with 4-5 elements? How do you define these "positions"? I cannot understand anything from your question, sorry... Please, try explaining **in words** of what you need/try accomplishing. What algorithm to be used to obtain 24, 20, 3, starting from 1, 2, 4? Should we analize your code which does not work as you want and guess?

Answer (score 0):

If you want adding an element an existing arran and it must be the first, please try understanding the next code logic. It loads an array from a range (directly) and then process it as (I understood) you need:

```
Sub AddNewArrayElementAsFirst()
   Dim array1, array2, range1 As Range, i As Long
   
   Set range1 = Range("A2:A4")
   array1 = range1.Value 'it automatically place the range values in the (2D) array
   Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(array1), "|") 'just to visually see the array content in Immediate Window
                                                                                                 'Ctrl + G (being in VBE) will bring Immediate Window
   
   Dim addedElement As Double: addedElement = 12.34
   ReDim array2(1 To UBound(array1) + 1, 1 To 1) 'redim the new array to have an extra row
   array2(1, 1) = addedElement 'place this element as the first
   For i = 1 To UBound(array1) 'iterate between the existing array elements to load the rest...
        array2(i + 1, 1) = array1(i, 1)
   Next i
   Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(array2), "|") 'to see the processing result, with the newly added element being the first one

   'if you want using array1, as the one with an extra element, VBA allows this way
    array1 = array2
    Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(array1), "|")

    'You can directly drop the array content in a range (In B:B, for instance):
    Range("B2").Resize(UBound(array2), 1).Value = array2
End Sub
```

If something not clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.